# Mount disk of non-selinux machine on machine with selinux enabled

Tags: rsync, backup, selinux, xattr

I have a backup server, which has selinux `enabled`. It has an external hard drive attached to it to store the backups (ext4).

I also have a workstation which has selinux `disabled`.

If I run rsync from the backup server in order to create a new backup for the workstation:

```
rsync -aAHSvX --delete --delete-excluded peter@workstation:/home/peter/ /home/peter/backup/
```

I get errors like this one for most files:

```
rsync: [receiver] rsync_xal_set: lremovexattr("/home/peter/backup/.Xauthority.z3D4Xf","security.selinux") failed: Permission denied (13)
```

It looks like the backup server automatically adds the `security.selinux` attribute to the xattrs of each file of the backup, since it has selinux enabled.

Does anyone know how I can prevent the backup machine from adding the `security.selinux` attributes to the files stored on the backup volume which is mounted at `/home/peter/backup`, in order to preserve the original attrs and in order to make rsync work properly?